# Fields of Attributes with Data Type Date are not in accordance with the Date format

Tags: marketing-cloud, date, fields, format, date-field

I am learning to use Marketing Cloud and something is not working the way I want it to be. When I make a Records in a Data Extension where one of the attribute Data Types is Date, the field shows the date in a different format than the Date Format I selected for the Business Unit I am working in.

How is this possible and how do i fix it?

Thanks,

Niels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of any settings you put on the business unit, all dates stored in a data extension follow the below rule:

> All dates are stored in the 12-hour format of MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS, and
>   if a date is entered in a different format, the system will convert it
>   to the proper format when storing it

This is shown in the '[data types](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_and_data_relationships/data_types/)' section describing the available options for field data types. You could always use this field as a text field and make your own formatting there. If you need it to be a date data type and need a specialized formatting for this, your only choice is to talk to your SFMC account rep and see what solution they can come up with.